# Combine multiple date fields into one on query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to create a report that counts a total from 2 date fields into one. A simplified example of the table I'm querying is:

```
ID, FirstName, LastName, InitialApplicationDate, UpdatedApplicationDate
```

I need to query the two date fields in a way that creates similar output to the following:

```
 Date | TotalApplications
```

I would need the date output to include both InitialApplicationDate and 
 UpdatedApplicationDate fields and the TotalApplications output to be a count of the total for both types of date fields. Originally I thought maybe a Union would work however that returns 2 separate records for each date. Any ideas how I might accomplish this?

Comment: update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: Do you want to count every instance of every date in both fields, or is there a logic for selecting one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way, I think, is to unpivot using `apply` and then aggregate:

```
select v.thedate, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (InitialApplicationDate), (UpdatedApplicationDate)) v(thedate)
group by v.thedate;
```

You might want to add `where thedate is not null` if either column could be `NULL`.

Note that the above will count the same application twice, once for each date.  That appears to be your intention.

Comment: Going to go ahead and accept this as the answer as it accomplished what I needed. It did produce different results than when I queried using LINQ.